# Using a different Microsoft Compiler Version with VisualStudio 2010 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I know it's possible to switch to a different "Platform Toolset" in Properties. Since I want to keep VisualStudio 2010 (plugins, etc) but also want to use C++11 features, how can I add a newer compiler version? The windows sdk does not come with a build pipeline anymore. I tried installing VisualStudio Express 2013, but that didn't help. I know I could just use the Express version, but I have several Plugins (EA, CodeXL) that I bought for VisualStudio2010.

Any hints would be appreciated

Comment: Should be easy enough by changing the VC++ Directories settings.  The iceberg that sinks that titanic is having to turn off the IntelliSense parser because it of course doesn't understand C++11 either.

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.